# How to get media URL with https connection from Rets server?

Tags: rets

Currently i am getting residential lease and media data from Rets server and displaying those information on my portal but i am getting media data with http conection from RETS server because of this my site does not secure. So, how can i get https connection for Medial URLs from Rets server?

Please anybody help me on this.

Best Regards,
Johson

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Hi Andrew Briggs, thank you for your reply. It is possible to get the media URLs with https connection? Please let me know on this.

Comment: Can you provide more details on this.
1) Media is a resource or Are you using GetObject().
2) Is this public image url supporting or not?